# Is there any way to check if all images in slick got loaded?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I want to set some other element height which depends on slick height. The calculation goes wrong because slick changes height after all images loaded.

Or is there way by which I can get slick height after loading it completely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be some heavy lifting for Slick, but there is another plug-in you should totally use and it's called ImagesLoaded
https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Example:

```
$(window).imagesLoaded(function () {
    // some code
});
```